# Music with lyrics about academic world

Tags: emotional-responses

I am curious to know if there are musicians or music bands whose compositions (in any musical style) have lyrics that talk about our "academia world" with songs, for instance "my manuscript was rejected twice", "happy day, my grant was accepted", "the nature paper that wasn't there", etc.

Comment: Not exactly about papers: https://youtu.be/60bU7K941nw

Comment: https://youtu.be/FID8pWyle0o

Comment: This is probably better for a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=academia.stackexchange.com) than a question on the main site, seeing as it's only tangentially related to academic pursuits, and it's collecting a list of indefinite length.

Comment: ["we have been unable to identify the particle shown in the image below"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsMLP3cheuc)

Comment: This would be awesome. 'Academitellica'?  'Pub Floyd?'  'Jay-Zscore?'